# Error while calling render_cell with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

> Showing
>   /home/anonym/Documents/RubyOnRails/cellHelloWorld/app/views/posts/show.html.erb
>   where line #14 raised:
>
> wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
>
> Extracted source (around line #14):
>
> 11:
>
> 12:  13: Lista uzytkownikow: 14: <%= render_cell(
>   :list_users, :display, {:user => 'aaa'} )%> 15:  16: <%= link_to
>   'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %>  17: <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path
>   %>
>
> Rails.root: /home/anonym/Documents/RubyOnRails/cellHelloWorld
>   Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>
> app/cells/list_users_cell.rb:3:in `display'
>   app/views/posts/show.html.erb:14:in`
>   _app_views_posts_show_html_erb__681305296_97982530'
>   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:19:in `show'

My cell file:

```
class ListUsersCell < Cell::Rails
  def display
    @users = Profile.all  
    render
  end
end
```

Calling it like this gives the same result

```
<%= render_cell(:list_users, :display, :user => 'aaa' )%>
```

Calling it like this works, but there are no arguments sent:

```
<%= render_cell(:list_users, :display )%>
```

So how can I pass some arguments to a cell?

Comment: What does the method :display look like in your actual Cell? Do you reference the method parameter in the method as they do in the "Implement" section of the Cells site:
http://cells.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Thanks, I should have define the function like this: "def display(args)". If you want to post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: No worries! If it's working now, that's all that matters (did adding the (args) to the method definition fix it?).

Comment: Yeap it did, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You define display method without params.

You should do something like this:

```
def display args
  @user = args[:user]     
  render
end
```